# jenkins pipeline unable to read files

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple Jenkinsfile where I want to load some data from the workspace. I am using the pipeline plugin to leverage the Jenkinsfile inside of the repository. The build is farmed off to a matching Jenkins agent. When I try to use "readFile" I get the following message:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /path/to/jenkins/workspace/XXXXX/project/data.json (No such file or directory)

I also get the same message when trying to load a Groovy file from the workspace.

My `Jenkinsfile` looks like:

```groovy
node('master') {
    stage "Start"
    echo "Starting"

    stage "Load File"
    def myJson = readFile "data.json"
}
```

Any ideas why I can't read these files?

Thanks,
 Tim

Comment: Is your _Configure System_ → _Workspace Root Directory_: `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}/project` or without the `/project`?

Comment: It is not. It's currently: ${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}

Comment: It looks like Jenkins is creating 3 workspaces on this build. 998-loops, 998-loops@script, and 998-loops@tmp. 998-loops@script is the only thing with any data in it. However, the other branch builds both XXX-topic and XXX-topic@script.

Comment: It looks like everything Jenkins tells the Jenkinsfile script is that its running out of the defined $WORKSPACE, without the @script. Even doing a pwd from within native groovy is telling the script that it's working within $WORKSPACE. This may be a bug.

Comment: User error, just noticed I don't have a "checkout scm" step. Wow, that was fun. Thanks for the help though Gerold!

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "putting a checkout scm step"? I've hit the same problem with the load function.

Comment: You would assume that once Jenkinsfile start processing that it has a copy of the repository contents. It does not. In order to bring the repo contents into the process you need 'checkout scm'
`
    node('master') {
        checkout scm

        stage "Start"
        echo "Starting"
    
        stage "Load File"
        def myJson = readFile "data.json"
    }
`

Comment: In my case, I was using various forms of `def myJson = new File('data.json').text` which failed with the same exception. Your question tipped me off to the `readFile` function, which I wasn't previously aware of. Fun fun fun.

Comment: @timcrider can you add an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 20):

When Jenkins processes a Jenkinsfile it does not automatically pull down the entire source repository. You need to execute "checkout scm" to pull down the contents of the repository. If you fail to do so no other files will be available to the pipeline script.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a valid requirement, that the op and others may have forgotten.

Comment: Why the downvote? It fixes my problem at least. Upvote.